# Sourcetree - open javascript file

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I try to open a javascript file from sourcetree, but it tries to execute it instead of opening the script in my editor:

[image: Open choosed version]

[image: compilation error in microsoft JScript]

Is there a way to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a workaround. Create a javascript dummy file somewhere, then right click and select "open with..." and select your favorite editor. Then click on the checkbox so that program is always going to be used.